# How can I make vim ignore a filetype plugin's makeprg setting?

Tags: filetype, makeprg, ftplugin

I am using a plugin that sets `makeprg` to some value specific to the filetype's programming language. I want to use my global setting instead, because I also use `Makefile`s. How can I do this? Thank you!

This happens for me with `vim-ledger` --- https://github.com/ledger/vim-ledger/blob/master/compiler/ledger.vim#L29-L31 --- and with `vim-racket` --- https://github.com/wlangstroth/vim-racket/blob/master/ftplugin/racket.vim#L36 --- When it happened for both, I assumed something was going wrong with me and I shouldn't be just commenting out lines of plugins on my local copy.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I'm afraid the problem relates to the plugin. I'm suspecting this is a plugin that overrides `makeprg` to compile mono-file projects. Are you using this plugin to compile? If so, it's likely that it'll override any setting you try to use, unless... there is something in the plugin to prevent that. You'll have to read its documentation, or contact its author, or try using another plugin.

Comment: @BLayer. I mean that a `:MakeInBackground` command from a plugin is likely to replace `&makeprg` with `g++ -o %< %` **on the fly** when the filetype is C++ for instance, instead of ([leaving `makeprg` alone in that particular case! ... :(](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/project/doc/make_run.md#mono-file-projects)) analysing the current context (is there a `Makefile`? a `CMakeFile.txt`? a `Sconsfile`? a user setting for the current buffer? and so on). Note: I expect that most trendy plugins support a `b:use_this_makeprg`-like option

Comment: Also, if the plugin specific commands are not used, I see no reason why `makeprg` would be overridden unless the plugin registers its own autocommands (or provides its own ftplugins). Unless some ftplugins run `:compiler {whatever}` -- I've seen this anti-pattern once or twice.

Comment: Jay can you edit your question and provide more details starting with which plugin you're using?

Comment: @LucHermitte Dispatch (tpope) doesn’t fall into this anti-pattern category, i don’t think (?)—one of my recent favorites

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I'd have been surprised if it would. :) Any way, I'm using a plugin I've been maintaining for ages that tries to autodetect targets (through project kind), compilation directories and a few other things. One of its origin comes from my attempts to fix/workaround compiler plugins (as in a same command like `make`, `ant`... we could run a compiler, a test unit tool, a documentation generator; we may also want to fix cygwin<->windows pathnames, and so on)

Comment: I updated the question with specific examples.

Comment: Both these "plugins" set `makeprg` locally for specific filetype only. It should not have any incidence on buffers with other filetypes. We may need to describe more precisally your workflow: what you do, what you observe and what you'd have wanted (to be sure)

Comment: In the case of vim-racket it does `setlocal makeprg=...` in ftplugin/racket.vim and to my knowledge that is exactly the kind of thing you can override with the method described in my answer. As for the other, I have a different plugin that does something identical: `setlocal makeprg=...` in a non-ftplugin file (in fact, also in a directory named "compiler"). In my testing that also was overridable using the "after directory" method as long as I chose the right filename (in my case asciidoc.vim). I think OP should be good to go with my answer...maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: My reading of the need is just to override `makeprg` for the specific filetypes touched by the plugins. Otherwise their global setting is fine. Jay, is that wrong or right?

Comment: I believe you are correct. I always want my global setting and never want the local settings of any filetypes. My preference would be to have one thing in my vimrc that will guarantee it can never be overridden, rather than having to do something special for every filetype, but I accept if that's not possible. Thank you!

Comment: @JayMcCarthy This may do it... create a file ~/.vim/after/ftdetect/makecheck.vim containing the following line: `au BufRead,BufNewFile *         if &makeprg != 'XXX' | set makeprg=XXX | endif`. Replace `XXX` with whatever your global setting is. (Note quotes on first instance, not second.)  Not a vimrc entry but it's a one-time deal...should work for all filetypes. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Actually, it's probably better to use `!=#` instead of `!=`. BTW, I did try this using a simple test and it worked but I wanted you to confirm before I add it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the plugin is using the standard scheme for filetype specific configuration...

Probably the simplest way to override is by creating a file in `$MYVIMDIR/after/ftplugin` with filename that matches the `filetype` (aka `ft`) setting when such a file is loaded. The plugin likely has a file of the same name and it will either be in directory `ftplugin` within its own installation directory or in the shared location for such files, `$MYVIMDIR/ftplugin`.

As an example, filetype specific settings for Java source files would be in a file named `java.vim` so to override you'd do:

```
vim ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/java.vim
```

(Assuming *nix style home directory.) Inside that file you'd then assign appropriate values to whatever settings you want to override.

In your specific case where you have a custom `'makeprg'` value you'll want to do:

```
set makeprg=<whatever>
```

(If you just wanted to reset to the default value you could do `set makeprg&`.)

You can find some additional details in the "DISABLING" section under [`:h ftplugin`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)

**Update:** So the above is a valid solution but requires taking action any time a new plugin that overrides `makeprg` comes along. OP wondered if there's a way to take care of current and future plugins in one fell swoop. This'll do the trick...

In your Vim "home directory" (e.g. `~/.vim`) create a file in `after/ftdetect`. Name doesn't matter. I chose `makecheck.vim`. Then add the following line to it:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile * if &makeprg !=# 'XXX' | set makeprg=XXX | endif
```

`XXX` should be replaced with whatever global `makeprg` value you're using.

As the name suggests, files in the `after` sub-tree get processed after other Vim files. This ensures the settings within aren't overwritten (by a plugin, for instance). It should be pretty self-explanatory how it works from there.

Comment: Why `after/ftdetect`? Those are generally used for setting filetypes. Perhaps `after/plugin` (or just `plugin`) is better?